# Upgrading from Java 8 to 11, why won't spring tests component scan properly?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, java-module

I'm beginning some upgrades to our infrastructure, updating some libraries to use Gradle 5.1 (from 4.2), Spring Boot 2 (from 1.5), Java 11 (from 8), and then with the goal of using the Java 11 module system.

I've made all the updates, and then my tests fail in the final step. It appears that when I instruct Gradle to run tests using the module-path, Spring isn't picking up my @Component objects, and my autowiring fails.

To be clear, the tests pass when using Java 11 and the default classpath, but fail once I add the `compileTestJava` and `test` gradle tasks shown below. (These tasks were based off of the example at the [gradle.org java 9 guide](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_test_code_task_to_consume_the_locally_altered_module)) The code still compiles (I've gotten past all the module related build errors) and the Spring context attempts to stand up when I get the error below.

When I use Spring to enable JPA repositories, it does find those classes (in different packages of the same project) and create singleton beans of them as expected. But when I run the test for a service that needs an instance of the service it is testing, it doesn't create that bean.

So the obvious question is why can my test no longer find those classes to create?

**build.gradle** (trimmed)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version "2.1"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.1.2.RELEASE"
    id 'maven-publish'
}

//sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    baseName = "my-jar"

    // For embedded tomcat apps
    manifest.attributes provider: 'gradle'
}

compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", "com.mypackage.academics")

    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()  
    }
}

compileTestJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", "com.mypackage.academics")
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath, 
            '--add-modules', 'junit',  
            '--add-reads', "com.mypackage.academics=junit", 
            '--patch-module', "com.mypackage.academics=" + "src/test/resources:" + files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs).asPath, 
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}

test {
    inputs.property("moduleName", "com.mypackage.academics")
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath, 
            '--add-modules', 'ALL-MODULE-PATH', 
            '--add-reads', "com.mypackage.academics=junit,spring.test,org.hamcrest", 
            '--patch-module', "com.mypackage.academics=" + "src/test/resources:" + files(sourceSets.test.java.outputDir).asPath, 
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

**module-info.java** (trimmed)

```
module com.mypackage.academics {
    exports com.mypackage.academics.config;

    opens com.mypackage.academics.config to org.hibernate.orm.core, spring.core;

    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.tx;
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mypackage.academics.config.AcademicsConfigService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at spring.beans@5.1.4.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651)
    at spring.beans@5.1.4.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at spring.beans@5.1.4.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    at spring.beans@5.1.4.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Without seeing `AcademicsConfigService` (Is it an interface or an implementation? Which annotations does the class have if it's a concrete class?) or the class which requires an `AcademicsConfigService` or your Spring-Application-Starter, I can just guess: 
1.: Try opening `com.mypackage.academics.config` to `spring.beans` and `spring.context` as well.
2.: Make sure that Spring can find your implementing class, e.g. by including it to the `scanBasePackages` of your Spring-Application-Starter's `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is expected behavior as far as Java 11 is concerned.

The issue is discussed in this thread.
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-July/054228.html

Basically, the way the tests are run sets up the application classes on the module path, while using the class path for test classes.

Comment: Based off of Gradle's documentation, that should be solved by the following:  



`'--patch-module', "com.mypackage.academics=" + "src/test/resources:" + files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs).asPath`